# Milnor's proof of differomeomorphism invaraince of the index of a vector

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading Milnor's Topology from the differentiable viewpoint.

There is a lemma as below,in page 33-35:

> Suppose that the vector field $v$ in $U$ corresponds to $v'=df \circ v
>  \circ f^{-1} $ on $U'$, under a diffeomorphism $f: U \to U'$. Then the
> index of $v$ at an isolated zero is equal to the index of $v'$ at
> $f(z)$

He prove the orientation preserving case as follows:

we construct a one-parameter family of embeddings
$$
f_{t}: U \rightarrow R^{m}
$$
with $f_{0}=$ identity, $f_{1}=f$, and $f_{t}(0)=0$ for all $t .$ Let $v_{t}$ denote the vector field $d f_{t} \circ v \circ f_{t}^{-1}$ on $f_{t}(U)$, which corresponds to $v$ on $U$. These vector fields are all defined and nonzero on a sufficiently small sphere centered at 0 . Hence the index of $v=v_{0}$ at 0 must be equal to the index of $v^{\prime}=v_{1}$ at 0 . This proves Lemma 1 for orientation preserving diffeomorphisms.

I know the idea is $v_0$ homotopic to $v_1$ which means they have the same index.The first question is about writing down the homotopy between $v_0$ and $v_1$ explicitly which involves choosing some domain.

The question is the choice of small neighborhood around 0,I mean for each $f_t$ we may choose some small sphere around 0 inside $f_t(U)$ if we can find a uniform small sphere,then we can define $v_t$ on the same domain say all $v_t$ defined on some $S^{n-1}(\epsilon)$ with $\epsilon$ independent of time $t$,hence the desired map is homotopic,I have no idea how to construct such small sphere.

The second question is where do we use the assumption that $U$ is convex?

Comment: Oh,I see why convex $U$ is needed here,Milnor construct the homotopy using $f(tx)/t$ when $t$ range the domain will pick all the point on the ray.So in fact here really needs the star shape of the region.

Comment: For the construction of your small sphere: for each $t \in [0,1]$ you find a small sphere with radius $\epsilon_t$. Now try to use a compactness argument.

Comment: I have considered this type of argument, I can't see why we can choose $\epsilon_t$ continuously?It depends on continuity of $f_t$@Maik Pickl

Comment: We may construct as follows,first consider the boundary of $f_t(U)$ which has positive distant to the origin (since $f_t$ diffeomorphic $U$ onto it hence $f_t(U)$ open)Hence we can choose some ball with $\epsilon_t = \frac{1}{2}dist(0,\partial f_t(U))$ if we can show it's continuous in $t$ then we are done.

Comment: Now the continuity of $\epsilon_t$ is obvious,since for $d(0,\partial f_t(U)) - d(0,\partial f_{t'}(U)) \le d(0,\partial  f_t(U)) - d(0,f_{t'}(y))+\epsilon/2 \le d(0,f_t(y)) -d(0,f_{t'}(y)) + \epsilon/2 \le \epsilon$ with $f_{t'}(y)$ is the one element on the boundary close to the distance,due to  continuity of $f_t$ in $t$ if $t$ and $t'$ are close enough